# Using a C++ function in pure C++ that calls for a boost::python object in its signature

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm trying to integrate some library functions written in boost::python into some C++ code I'm using. I have unit tests written for the pure C++ versions of these functions, and I'd like to be able to run them on the boost::python versions as well. However, I'm running into an (expected I presume) issue with this, namely that the function signature expecting a boost::python object isn't recognized as applicable to the C++ code:

```
template<typename T>
static std::vector<T> contains(std::vector<T>& originalVector, boost::python::object fc)
{
     check to see if originalVector contains either a specific value or if a function evaluates to true for any value of the array
}
```

With the following test:

```
//Testing to see if a vector contains a single element

// SETUP
std::vector<int> originalVector = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
int targetValue = 4;
bool isExpected = true; 

// EXERCISE
bool isActual = Array::contains(originalVector, targetValue);

// VERIFY
ASSERT_EQ(isExpected, isActual);
```

Gives the error message:

`error: no matching function for call to 'contains' Array::contains(originalVector, subVector);`

I'm new to boost::python, but I'd imagine that this is a semi-common occurrence and that there must be some way to copy/cast the incoming python object appropriately to allow the function to be called from pure C++.

Thanks for any advice that you might have.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you with your problem exactly, but this documentation might be useful: https://boostorg.github.io/python/doc/html/article.html